# Focusing a button at a samsung activity

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

It is known from another discussions that the samsung battery monitor can be reached by starting the activity "com.samsung.android.sm.ui.battery.BatteryActivity".

Is it possible (maybe using some extras) to focus on the "Unmonitored apps" button ?

[image: Samsung app monitor]

Comment: I know some apps can do this, so it is possible.  But how?!  I think this whole Samsung battery flow is clumsy and redundant.